# Unable to calculate the checksum of the remote file persist with validate_checksum equal false/no

Tags: ansible

How to handle the error below? I tried it with `validate_checksum: no`, any suggestions?

***Playbook:***

```
- name: "Collect file"
  hosts: WIN
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: 'Copy file'
          fetch:
            src: "D:\\Soft\\Program Files (x86)\\connect.cfg"
            dest: "/etc/files/connect.cfg"
            flat: yes
            validate_checksum: no
      rescue:
        - fail:
            msg: "Failure detected in playbook"
```

***Error:***

```
Unable to calculate the checksum of the remote file
```

***Hosts:***

```
[Windows]
WIN

[Windows:vars]
ansible_ssh=192.168.9.102
ansible_port=5985
ansible_user=domain\username
ansible_password="pass123"
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start with checking the source file by adding the following code block before your 'Copy file'

```yaml
    - name: Get file properties
      stat:
        path: "D:\\Soft\\Program Files (x86)\\connect.cfg"
        register: result
    - name: All properties
      debug:
        var: result.stat
    - name: Checksum
      debug:
        var: result.stat.checksum
```

A brute force way to move past the error is just to add `ignore_errors: yes` in place of `validate_checksum: no`

Comment: I added the hosts file to the question

Comment: I got the output below: `[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host WIN: plaintext: HTTPConnectionPool(host='WIN', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb21ab315d0>, 'Connection to WIN timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))` - But the door is listening: `/etc/ansible/playbook # socksify telnet 192.168.9.102 5985 Trying 192.168.9.102... Connected to 192.168.9.102. Escape character is '^]'. ^CConnection closed by foreign host.`